# Jquery mobile plus/minus issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I was going to use jQuery mobile for this one to get the mobile theme http://jsfiddle.net/hhken790/

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" />
<input type="text" name="myInputs[qty][]" value="0" class="qty" />
<input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#dynamic").on("click", ".qtyplus", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input  = $(this).prev("input");
    var currentVal = parseInt($input.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
       $input.val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
       $input.val(0);
    }
});
```

However, the plus and minus wont work here. Any idea what causing this?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome? Is the mobile theme applied. For me it does not work in Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add jQM, it enhances/styles many DOM elements by adding container divs and other DOM elements. This means that your buttons and text inputs are no longer siblings in the DOM and prev() will not work. Instead traverse up the DOM and then down:

```
var $input  = $(this).closest("div#dynamic").find(".qty");
```

e.g:

```
$("#dynamic").on("click", ".qtyplus, .qtyminus", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var $input  = $(this).closest("div#dynamic").find(".qty");
    var currentVal = parseInt($input.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $(this).hasClass("qtyplus") ? $input.val(currentVal + 1) : $input.val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        $input.val(0);
    }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hhken790/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I was using the `.prev` as I was adding more quantity fields by clicking `<input type="button" value="Add another qty input" onClick="addInput('dynamic')">` which generated a new set of Qty +/-. So the new code will update all qty-fields and not just the active one.

Comment: @user3419021, in your dynamic code you are placing the controls within a containing DIV. just give that div a class and use that when traversing the DOM:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hhken790/4/

Comment: Perfect, that sorted it. Thanks for all the help